# Does "quel(les)" ever appear in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: oral

I'm finding understanding spoken French to be very difficult. One reason is because of homophones.

Whenever I hear "qu'elle" in a sentence, my brain thinks of "quel" (or quels/quelle/quelles). I realized, though, that I have never seen a sentence with "quel" in the middle of a sentence.

So, does quel ever appear in the middle of a sentence? If it does not, and I hear something that sounds like "quel" in the middle of a sentence, I'll realize that instead it is probably "qu'elle" that was said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, « quel » peut apparaître au milieu d'une phrase, comme dans « Je ne sais pas quel est ce personnage », soit « I don't know which character it is ».

Comment: Yep. Reported speech and "mashup" sentences (as noted by LEI below) are pretty much the only cases where this can occur.

Answer (score 1):

It is an [interrogative and exclamatory adjective](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/quel_quelle/65610), more on interrogatif from Larousse:

> *Mot (adjectif, pronom, adverbe) interrogatif.*
>
> La classe des mots interrogatifs rassemble, en français, des adjectifs (**quel ?** et ses variantes), des pronoms (qui ? que ? quoi ? **lequel ? duquel ? auquel ?** et leurs variantes), des adverbes (où ? combien ? comment ? etc.) et des locutions (est-ce-que ? qui est-ce-qui ? etc.).
>
> La phrase interrogative se distingue de la phrase assertive par la présence d'une intonation montante, un ordre différent des mots (inversion du pronom sujet) et/ou la présence de termes interrogatifs.

Be aware of the [variations](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/lequel_laquelle_lesquels_lesquelles/46743), which sound the same and can be found in the middle more often:

> Le livre dans lequel j'ai lu cette histoire.
>
> Les gens au nom desquels je parle.

I think *quel(le)* can be used in the interrogative or exclamatory form after punctuation, but it might appear as two sentences when spoken with intonation:

> C'était magnifique, quel spectacle inoubliable !
>
> Je n'ai pas regardé la météo, quel temps fait-il ?